# Using slots to determine the element that is clickable/triggers the input event of an invisible type="file" input tag

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuejs-slots

I have a base component that should have the ability to upload multiple files to firestore. Since I want to be able to use this component across multiple points in my app, I want to take advantage of slots so I can change the element that is covering the hidden input tag. So whether it be a button, an svg, etc. I still want the input to trigger the click event.

Currently, only the default `img` tag works to trigger the `@change` event.

Do I need to pass more props? How can I make this work in my current state?

If you need anymore information please let me know!

Cheers!

Note: I've yet to get the multiple file selection for firestore upload working, but am working on it.

**UploadMediaFiles.vue** (child)

```html
<template>
  <div class="upload-media-files">
    <input
      id="input-file"
      type="file"
      accept="image/*"
      @change="addMedia"
      class="_add-media-input"
    />
   <label for="input-file">
    <slot>
        <img
          src="https://www.clipartmax.com/png/middle/142-1422132_png-file-svg-upload-file-icon-png.png"
          alt=""
        />
    </slot>
   </label>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'UploadMediaFiles',
  props: {
    multiple: { type: Boolean },
    accept: { type: String },
  },
  data() {
    return {
      files: [],
    }
  },
  computed: {},
  methods: {
    async addMedia(event) {
      const selectedFiles = event.target.files
      console.log(`selectedFiles → `, selectedFiles)
      this.files.push(selectedFiles)
      this.$emit('selected', this.files)
    },
  },
}
</script>
```

**SelectAndPreviewFiles** (parent)

```html
<template>
  <div class="select-and-preview-files">
    <UploadMediaFiles accept="image/*" :multiple="true" @selected="(files) => doSomething(files)">
      <button>upload file</button>
    </UploadMediaFiles>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import UploadMediaFiles from '../atoms/UploadMediaFiles.vue'
export default {
  name: 'SelectAndPreviewFiles',
  components: {
    UploadMediaFiles,
  },
  props: {},
  data() {
    return {}
  },
  computed: {},
  methods: {
    doSomething(files) {
      console.log(`files → `, files)
    },
  },
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could pass a method to the slot that invokes the hidden input's `click`-handler:

1. In `UploadMediaFiles`, add a template ref to the input:

   ```html
   <input ref="myInput">
   ```
2. In `UploadMediaFiles`, create a component method that invokes the input's `click`-handler:

   ```js
   export default {
     methods: {
       openFileDialog() {
         this.$refs.myInput.click()
       }
     }
   }
   ```
3. In `UploadMediaFiles`, pass the component method to the slot:

   ```html
   <slot :openFileDialog="openFileDialog">
   ```
4. In `SelectAndPreviewFiles`, bind the slot prop as your button's `click`-handler:

   ```html
   <UploadMediaFiles v-slot="{ openFileDialog }">
     <button @click="openFileDialog">Upload files</button>
   </UploadMediaFiles>
   ```

[demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/passing-event-handler-as-slot-prop-kncn9?file=/src/components/SelectAndPreviewFiles.vue)

Comment: Thank you for in depth reply!
This works just the way I want! I suspect that I could just add that `@click="openFileDialog"` to any tag I use as a slot then huh? Very cool.